# IPython Notebook - Start using default Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have been setting up some IPython Notebooks on public servers for training purposes.

Once logged in, you are taken to the default landing page where you can choose the Notebook you want, create a new one and since IPython 2.0 navigate directories.

I would however like to serve a default Notebook upon logging in. This would make it possible for the student to log in and automatically be taken to a notebook that was set up with some instructions.

Of course he/she could just click on the link but it would just make it easier and better looking if it could start with a default page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pre 2.0 IPython clicking on a notebook link took you to a temporary kernel address (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8889/10327f95-f1f6-4016-80f0-e23c477edbfe`).

Since 2.0 these links are permanent so you can just provide direct notebook links to your students, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/Test.ipynb`